# What I need to put in String urlAddress in Java class, cause 127.0.0.1 doesn't make it work

Tags: java, php, mysql

I want to do a search listview apps that connect with database using PHPMyAdmin.
Language PHP and Java.

This is coding class for LNSsearch.java

```
public class LNSsearch extends AppCompatActivity {

String urlAddress = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/search.php";
Toolbar toolbar;
SearchView searchView;
ListView lv;
ImageView noresultfound, noconnection;
```

This is my database server details.

```
Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.1.13-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version: 10
User: 
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

This is my PHP file:

```
<?php
$host='127.0.0.1';
$username='root';
$pwd='';
$db="epv3";

$con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$pwd,$db) or die('Unable to connect');


if(mysqli_connect_error($con))
{
   echo "Failed to Connect to Database".mysqli_connect_error();
}

$comp_no=$_POST['Query'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM t_comp WHERE comp_no LIKE '%$comp_no%'";
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if($query)
{
   while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
   {
      $data[]=$row;
   }

    print(json_encode($data));
}

else
{
  echo ('Not Found');
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: "doesn't make it work" meaning?

Comment: Oh and http://bobby-tables.com/php

Comment: i have tried use this ip address, 127.0.0.1 but it doesn't work after i run in localhost. how can i get the ip address on this line ?
String urlAddress = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/search.php";